# RFID code visual Studio error 1

Tags: c#, c++, raspberry-pi3

Im trying to compile a simple code for rfid card and export it to my Pi 3 through ssh using visualGDB. but i get the following error . Ive included the header file for the card and the necessary library files.
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   ld returned 1 exit status   rfidtest

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <MFRC522.h>


void delay(int ms) {
#ifdef WIN32
Sleep(ms);
#else
usleep(ms * 1000);
#endif
}

int main() {
MFRC522 mfrc;

mfrc.PCD_Init();

while (1) {
    // Look for a card
    if(!mfrc.PICC_IsNewCardPresent())
      continue;

    if (!mfrc.PICC_ReadCardSerial())
        continue;

    // Print UID
    for(byte i = 0 ; i < mfrc.uid.size ; ++i) {
        if (mfrc.uid.uidByte[i] < 0x10) {
            printf(" 0");
            printf("%X", mfrc.uid.uidByte[i]);
        }
        else {
            printf(" ");
            printf("%X", mfrc.uid.uidByte[i]);
        }

    }
    printf("\n");
    delay(1000);
}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Down at the bottom of Visual Studio you usually find a group of tabs including "Error List" (the default), "Output", and some others that don't matter here. Change from "Error List" to "Output" this gives longer-form error messages (and a load of other build information) in text that you can easily copy and paste into Stack Overflow questions and is far more useful. What we can determine is you are facing a linker error, and the current error message unfortunately leaves out what failed to link, giving us out here very little to work with.

Comment: 1>------ Build started: Project: rfidtest, Configuration: Debug VisualGDB ------
1>Linking ../VisualGDB/Debug/rfidtest...
1>c:/sysgcc/raspberry/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/6/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lMFRC522
1>c:/sysgcc/raspberry/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/6/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -l-Wl,--rpath=$ORIGIN
1>collect2.exe : error : ld returned 1 exit status
1>Done building project "rfidtest.vcxproj" -- FAILED.
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========

Comment: See if you can find the full linker command line. `cannot find -lMFRC522` means pretty much what it sounds like, so you may have neglected to specify a path, but `cannot find -l-Wl,--rpath=$ORIGIN` hints that the command line itself may be incorrect.

Comment: ok. Which command line and im not sure what that line  cannot find -lMFRC522 can mean. I have the include directories pointed at what i want

Comment: My apologies. `-l<library name>` means link in the named library, so `cannot find -lMFRC522` means, "You asked me to link in lMFRC522, but I don't know where it is." You can fix this by adding `-L<path to library>` to the command line, but unfortunately I don't have the slightest idea how to do that when using Visual Studio with GCC. Nor do I know where in the output crawl you find the command line. I've never used GCC with Visual Studio.

Comment: why does it add -l to the name . The library file name is MFRC522.h not -lMFRC522

Comment: The `-l` is a command line switch, not  apart of the name. It is a message to the command parser so that the parser will know to use what follows as a library that needs to be linked.

Comment: ive linked the required libraries and it still wont budge. when i use this line on the terminal g++ MFRC522.cpp Read.cpp -std=++11 -lbcm2835 the file compiles and it wokrs fine.